# How to create both Android application and website using same backend laravel backend

Tags: android, laravel, api, backend

I am developing a E-commerce website and application and i want same backend for both app and web how can i do this in laravel?

Comment: This single question contains enough hidden complexity to fill an entire semester's worth of lectures on the topic. I suggest you start your learning process from books, tutorials and ecourses to learn about the fundumentals of developing apps for the web. StackOverflow is a site that is meant to help you answer programming questions and that can only happen after you've started programming something, by helping you with things regarding specific aspects of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it by creating API routes and having your website & apps use them.